# Create WooCommerce Product save product id to ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

So currently I created a custom button on my custom post type "vault" that when clicked it will turn the info of that custom post type into a WooCommerce product. Once the WooCommerce product is created it should pass back the product ID and save it to a ACF field called woo_product_id. Currently it's not saving the product ID to that field but the product is being created.

Here is my code:

```
// Hook to save ACF field after custom post type is created or updated
function save_acf_field_to_custom_post_type($vault_id, $acf_field_value) {
    // Check if it's the desired custom post type
    if (get_post_type($vault_id) === 'vault') {
        // Check if the ACF field value is provided
        if ($acf_field_value !== null) {
            // Update the post meta with the ACF field value
            update_post_meta($vault_id, 'woo_product_id', $acf_field_value);
        }
    }
}

// Create Sell Button
function blz_add_sell_button_to_vault( $post ) {
    // Checking its the correct post type
    if ( get_post_type( $post ) == 'vault' ){
        echo '<div class="email-buttons" style="padding-right:20px;"><input id="make-product" class="button-primary" name="make-product" type="submit" value="Move To Store" /></div>';
    } 
} 
add_action('post_submitbox_minor_actions', 'blz_add_sell_button_to_vault', 10, 2 );

/** 
 * Create Product in WooCommerce
 * 
 * @param integer $post_ID
 * @param WP_Post $post
 * @param boolean $update
 * @return void
 *  */ 
function blz_check_if_send_email_button_pushed(int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update){ 
    if ( key_exists( 'make-product', $_POST ) && $_POST['make-product'] == 'Move To Store'){ 

        // Get Models Basic Info
        $figureInfo = get_post($post_ID);
        $figureName = $figureInfo->post_title;
        $figurePrice = get_field('price');
        $figurePhoto = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_ID);
        $figureSlug = basename(get_permalink($post_ID));

        $figurePhotos = array();

        foreach (get_field('photo_gallery') as $images) {
            array_push($figurePhotos, $images['ID']);
        }
        
        // Pass Figure info to WooCommerce
        $product = new WC_Product_Simple();

        $product->set_name($figureName); // product title

        $product->set_slug($figureSlug);

        $product->set_regular_price( $figurePrice ); // in current shop currency

        $product->set_image_id( $figurePhoto );

        $product->set_gallery_image_ids($figurePhotos);

        $product->save();

        save_acf_field_to_custom_post_type($figureInfo->ID, '123456');

    } 
} 

add_action( 'save_vault_post', 'blz_check_if_send_email_button_pushed', 10, 3 );
```